# Forming a recurrence relation from tiling a block

Tags: proof-verification, recurrence-relations

Suppose we wish to tile a $2\times n$ rectangular board with smaller tiles of $1\times 2$ and $2\times 2$ blocks.
Let $a_n$ be the number of ways this can be done.
Find a recurrence relation for $a_n$.

This is my attempt:
The area of our big block is $2n$. Suppose we tile it initially with a $2\times 2$ block. Then the remaining area is $2n-4 = 2(n-2)$. The rest of this can be tiled in $a_{n-2}$ ways.

Now, suppose we tile it initially with a $1\times 2$ block. Intuitively, we must, in the future, tile it with another $1\times 2$ block. Now once we place the $1\times 2$ block down, we have a joint piece of $1\times 2$ and a $2\times (n-2)$ block to fill. We fill the latter in $a_{n-2}$ ways. The former can be filled in $n/2$ ways (since it depends where we initially tiled the $1\times 2$.
So total is
$$a_n = 2a_{n-2} + \frac{n}{2}.$$
However, the solution is $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}$.
Where in my flow of logic did I go wrong and how can I get their solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that here the tile $1\times 2$ can be rotated (otherwise $2\times n$ board can not be tiled when $n$ is odd).

Now the last tile in the board $2\times n$ can be:
$$\text{a $2\times 1$ rectangle, or a $2\times 2$ square, or a pair of $2\times 1$ rectangles.}$$ 
Since these final tiles yield distinct tilings, we have that for $n\geq 3$,
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-2}=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}.$$
Note that $a_1=1$, $a_2=3$.