# Recurrence Relation Discrete Maths

Tags: recurrence-relations, tiling

Could I know how to start with this kind of problem? Thanks.

Let $T_n$ be the number of ways of tiling a $2\times n$ rectangle using tiles of dimensions $1 \times 2$ or $2 \times 2$.
For example, the picture below shows one of the tiling counted by $T_{12}$
[image]

Find (and justify!) a recurrence relation and initial conditions that $T_n$ satisfies.

Comment: It's always useful to draw pictures. Assume that you have a tiling of length $k$. Because there are two different tiles (and three ways to put them, I think?), you have to consider three different cases. So the goal is to grow $k$ to $k+1$ ...

Comment: Initial condition should be easy - what is $T_1$?

Comment: Where's "the picture below"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forming a recurrence relation from tiling a block](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474808/forming-a-recurrence-relation-from-tiling-a-block)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you already have a tiled rectangle.  How can you extend it to the right to get a bigger rectangle?  There are $3$ ways.  You could add a single $1\times2$ tile vertically, or a single $2\times2$ tile, or two $1\times2$ tiles horizontally.

Now just turn this around to get $T_n$ in terms of $T_{n-1}$ and $T_{n-2}$.  You need $2$ initial conditions, the values for $T_1$ and $T_2$.  Do you see why?